# Extract Data From Multiple Files

Tags: java, html, text, extract

I have exactly 278 Html files of essays from different students, every file contains student id, first name and last in the following format

```
<p>Student ID: 000000</p>
<p>First Name: John</p>
<p>Last Name: Doe</p>
```

I'm trying to extract Student IDs from all this files, is there a way to extract data between X and Y? X being "`<p>Student ID:` " and Y being "`</p>`" which should leave us with ID

What Method/Language/Concept/Software would you recommend to get this work done?

Comment: I tried some softwares but they all either asked to pay a fortune or spread viruses on my pc, I'm a programmer myself, I know html, css, basic java, I'm keen to learn new language to get this work done. Thanks

Comment: will each file contains only one tag <p>Student ID: 000000</p>?

Comment: there are other <p> tags as well in the html document if that's what you mean but only one  <p>Student ID: 000000</p>

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using java:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.file.FileSystems;
import java.nio.file.Files;
import java.nio.file.Path;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class StudentIDsRetriever {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        File dir = new File("htmldir");
        String[] htmlFiles = dir.list();
        List<String> studentIds = new ArrayList<>();
        List<String> emailDs = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String htmlFile : htmlFiles) {
            Path path = FileSystems.getDefault().getPath("htmldir", htmlFile);
            List<String> lines = Files.readAllLines(path);
            for (String str : lines) {
                if (str.contains("<p>Student ID:")) {
                    String idTag = str.substring(str.indexOf("<p>Student ID:"));
                    String id = idTag.substring("<p>Student ID:".length(), idTag.indexOf("</p>"));
                    System.out.println("Id is "+id);
                    studentIds.add(id);
                }

                if (str.contains("@") && (str.contains(".com") || str.contains(".co.in"))) {
                    String[] words = str.split(" ");
                    for (String word : words) 
                        if (word.contains("@") && (word.contains(".com") || word.contains(".co.in"))) 
                            emailDs.add(word);
                }

            }
        }
        System.out.println("Student list is "+studentIds);
        System.out.println("Student email list is "+emailDs);
    }
}
```

P.S: This works from Java7+

Comment: You my friend is the real legend of my life

Comment: I know I have asked alot already but is there anyways you would be able to help me one more? apparently I also have to extract emails, and email is more tricky because it isn't neatly written like id and name, its more like something@something.com

is there any way we can copy the word after and before@ symbol before we hit a space? which should leave us with the email? Thanks alot, any help will make my day

Comment: extremely sorry for a late reply, went out for a meal. here's what it looks like

<p>Student ID: 000000</p>
<p>First Name: John</p>
<p>Last Name: Doe</p>
[Essay]

johnDoe@gmail.com

Ps: not all of them are gmail.com so the only pattern i see is the @ symbol

Answer (score 0):

I recommand you python script. If you first use python, It's OK. python is so easy script language and has many references in google.

1) Language: **python** (version 2.7)

2) Library: **beautifulsoup** (you can download this with pip(pip is package manager program, pip can be installed in python installer)

traverse files one by one and open your local files. and parse HTML content using beautifulsoup. (see this part https://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/#tag)

**then, extract content from <p> tag. It return "Student ID: 000000".**

split this string with ":". this return str[0] and str[1].

str[1] is student number you want (maybe you erase space character... call *'   Hel   lo  '.strip()* -> Hello

If you need a help, reply.